# Pure CSS radial timer with Django

Tags: html, css, django

I know that it's possible to create timed animations in pure CSS, and I've been able to get a 5 minute radial timer working in CSS the way I'd like.

I'm just getting started with Django, and I'm curious whether I can make this functional for users. If someone visits my page, would Django be able to pull their visit time and pass it to the CSS animation, so that the animation is at the same point in the progression for all visitors? Is there any way to make the animation progression persistent upon page refresh as well?

I'm very interested to know if there is any JavaScript-free solution to this, even if it is unwieldy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In your view you could pass a context to your HTML template containing the time the request was sent. Then on your HTML template, you could set a CSS custom property with the context passed.

```html
<style>

:root {
  --hour: {{hour}}
  --minute: {{minute}}
  --second: {{second}}
}

</style>
```

In your view, you could use `datetime` to get the hour, minute, and second.

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
return render(request, 'page.html', {'hour': now.hour, 'minute': now.minute, 'second': now.second})
```

Comment: Note that the style tag must be on the actual HTML template, and not in a seperate file.

Comment: I see. Why does it need to be on the actual HTML template and not a separate file? Would I be able to use a separate file for the code for my CSS timer, or would that also need to be in the HTML template?

Comment: You can use a seperate file for the timer, and then import that in from your `style` tag. The reason that the variable needs to be in the template is because Django won't parse any css or js imported by your template. Therefore, we need to keep any context passing in the template so Django will recognize it.