# Setting a CSS variable in Django

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I am creating custom user pages where they are able to change basic features like the font, color, or background color of different link boxes. Currently, I am passing the saved variables from the database to the HTML template but I was wondering if I could pass them into the external CSS style sheet. I am having to do inline CSS styling inside the HTML template. I'd like the link hover effect to stay but whenever I set the background color of the link via inline CSS in my HTML template it will break the hover effect.

Note: Only including part of my index.html file

`index.html`

```html
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}"/>

<div id="links">
   <a class="link" style="color:{{ linkcolor }}; background-color:{{ linkbc }}; font-family:{{ linkfont }};" href="https://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><Instagram</a>
</div>
```

`style.css`

```css
#links {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.link {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: all .25s cubic-bezier(.08, .59, .29, .99);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
}
```

`views.py`

```py
def index(request):
    editor = cssEditor.objects.get(pk=1)

    return render(
        request,
        "SocialLinks/index.html",
        {
            "linkcolor":editor.link_color,
            "linkfont":editor.link_font,
            "linkbc":editor.link_bc
        }
    )
```

`models.py`

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class cssEditor(models.Model):
    link_color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#000000")
    link_font = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="Brush Script MT")
    link_bc = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#F5F5F5")
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to easily do this in a separate CSS file. Your best bet is to make the values you want to override available in the template's `context` and put those in the `head`.

Comment: Yeah, that is basically what I have seen as well. Just getting a bit tedious to create a bunch of inline CSS styling. When you say to put it in the `head` what do you mean? Put the `<style></style>` tags in the head of the template and set the CSS variables in there? Currently, I am just doing it all inline and it is getting a bit tedious.

Comment: You can use custom properties to not have to repeat yourself all the time. See my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065936/pure-css-radial-timer-with-django/69066380#69066380

Comment: Strictly speaking `style` should go in an HTML page's `head`, but it doesn't have to. @Arandomcoder explains what we both are trying to suggest in his linked answer.